# How to download file from google drive link in android studio download manager?

Tags: android

I want to download file using google drive link in my android app.The links are given by the users.The users upload files url.Then they can also download it.How can I convert drive link into direct download link automatically?
From this- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B06LDsRAizsTc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl/view?usp=sharing
To- https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B06LDsRAizsTc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl

How can I convert it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give out your google drive download link to users but you have to first make your google drive content you would like to share public.
To do this follow this guide

a. Login into your **Google Drive**

b. Select the document that you want to make Public

c. Right click on the document and select **Share option**

d. Click on **Advanced** button

e. from Sharing Setting window, click **Change** link On Link Sharing window, and select **Public** on the web option

f. click on **Save** and the link will be done

Then use URL shortner to shorten and serve the link to your users.
you can use bitly.com or any other website url shortner that will serve you.
Goodluck!

Comment: I know how can make shareable link but I want to convert those shareable link into downloadable link in my app automatically. Thanks For your answer

Comment: Okay maybe you need to implore the method i am using to create auto download and/or copy-link. Go to this Google link and create link https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/

Comment: If this answers your questions click accept answer for others to learn from it.

Comment: I don't want to do it manually .I want automatically in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply process string to generate the downloadable link.

I did it in my app in the following way:

```java
    public static String getFinalUrl(String pdfUrl) {
        String documentId = getDocumentId(pdfUrl);
        pdfUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + documentId;
        return pdfUrl;
    }


    public static String getDocumentId(String pdfUrl) {
        int beginIndex = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/".length();
        int endIndex = pdfUrl.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (endIndex < 0) {
            endIndex = pdfUrl.length();
        }
        String documentId;
        try {
            documentId = pdfUrl.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        return documentId;
    }
```

Here, `getFinalUrl()` returns the desired url using which we can download file. I needed to write a method for downloading pdf file so I named the variable for the url as `pdfUrl`. But **it should work for any file**.